# how to replace a pilcrow symbol using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a load of ¶ paragraph symbols in my data.

I have 10 different columns that i need to check.

I would like to search for it and then replace it with a carriage return. How can i do this via SQL?

I know i can do  this in mySQL:

```
UPDATE table1 SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield,'¶','\r\n') WHERE myfield LIKE '%¶%'
-- cariage return+linefeed.
```

But how can i do this in MSSQL server?

Comment: `declare @str nvarchar(max) = N'I ¶have a ¶load of ¶ paragraph ¶symbols in ¶my data.';
select REPLACE(@str,'¶','')`

Comment: An answer would be good... I have updated my question..

Comment: you can do same as in MS SQL

Comment: i need to replace with carriage return... can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ascII value

```
SELECT ascii('¶')
```

Returns `182`

```
UPDATE table1 
SET  myfield = REPLACE(myfield, CHAR(182), '\r\n') 
WHERE  myfield like '%'+CHAR(182)+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `REPLACE`

```
UPDATE table1 
SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield,N'¶',CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)) 
WHERE myfield LIKE N'%¶%';
```

`Tinka demo` upgraded:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'I ¶have a ¶load of ¶ paragraph ¶symbols in ¶my data.'; 

PRINT REPLACE(@str,N'¶',CHAR(10) + CHAR(13));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379037)**</kbd>

Comment: I definately have the pilcrow value in my datasource text file but in the database i cannot see it in the table. Is there a char value for the symbol that i could search for?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Share sample data

Comment: @PriceCheaperton This is how it looks like in DB or file?

Comment: it looks like a space in the database.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Share table structure and how you insert data

Comment: @PriceCheaperton See demo. If data is there solution is already provided. Probably you insert not as `¶` and you are dealing with some garbage. It cannot be space